# sessionStorage not persisting between pages

Tags: javascript, html, sessionstorage

My understanding is that sessionStorage values should persist after page reloads, but also between pages in the same site as long as the same tab is used.

In a particular page I can set 2 sessionStorage values. They persist on reload and when I come back to that page from another.

I need to pick up these values on another page in the same site but I cannot. 
Am I missing something in the documentation that states this is not possible or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried localStorage also but same problem.

Given a scenario where my 2 sessionStorage values are set, I test for them with the following if statement, but it never gets to it. I have also tried logging each to the console but no luck.

Thanks.

```
if (Modernizr.sessionstorage) {
var
a = document.getElementById('aId'),
b = document.getElementById('bId'),
c = document.getElementById('cId'),
d = document.getElementById('dId'),
e = document.getElementById('eId'),
f = parseInt(b.value)*parseInt(d.value)+4;

var startValues = function (){
a.value = b.value;
c.value = d.value;
e.value = f;
};

var sessValues = function (){
b.value = sessionStorage.getItem('thingOne');
d.value = sessionStorage.getItem('thingTwo');
startValues();
};


if(sessionStorage.getItem('thingOne') !== null || sessionStorage.getItem('thingTwo') !== null){
   sessValues();
}

else{
    sessionStorage.setItem('thingOne', 1);
    sessionStorage.setItem('thingTwo', 1);
    startValues();
}


b.addEventListener('input', function () {
sessionStorage.setItem('thingOne', b.value);
a.value = b.value;
}, false);

d.addEventListener('input', function () {
sessionStorage.setItem('thingTwo', d.value);
c.value = d.value;
}, false);
```

}

Comment: Can you please provide the sessValues function code (if that is the one that sets them) or expose your code where you actually set the data?

Comment: Possibly your code on this page resets the `sessionStorage` values because normally you do get sessionStorage items on another page if opened in same tab.

Comment: just added full code block now

Answer (score 1):

Apologies. Completely caught up in testing locally. All fine on a server. Got prompt from here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924387/sessionstorage-in-firefox?rq=1)